# can some one explain what is iv = enc[:16] and enc= enc[16:] means?

Tags: python-3.x

```
iv = enc[:16] 
enc= enc[16:]
```

what is the meaning of above:

as of now using it in blunt way so please explain, just wanted to know the meaning of what I'm using ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you're assigning the first 16 characters of `enc` to `iv` and the rest of the characters back to `enc`:

```
string = "abcdefg"
print(string[:3]) # abc
print(string[3:]) # defg
```